# List Array and String Array / multi-line string inside of nested loop in Android Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I've got a string with many lines and in each line contains a number of elements. I'm only after a third element of each line. 
Is there anything from with this chunk of code?

```
String[] separate = getArray().split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < separate.length; i++)
{
    String[] inner = separate[i].split("/");
    for (int y = 0; y < inner.length; y++)
    {
        _listArray.add(String.valueOf(inner[2]));                   
    }
}
```

it's not doing what it's supposed to, or maybe I'm just too tired.

Comment: You have to describe the problem better than "it's not doing what it's supposed to".  How is it not working?

Comment: Are you sure that getArray() returns the original string in the correct format with all the lines separated by \n ?

Comment: Why are you calling `String.valueOf( )`?  `inner[2]` is already a `String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inner loop is not needed.

```
String[] lines = getArray().split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
  String[] tokens = line.split("/");
  _listArray.add(tokens[2]);
}
```

You may want a safety to make sure that `tokens.length >= 2`

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it suppose to be:

```
String[] separate = getArray().split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < separate.length; i++)
{
String[] inner = separate[i].split("/");
if(inner.length<3)
     throw new RuntimeException("Wrong data");//or ignore line as desire
else _listArray.add(String.valueOf(inner[2]));                   
}
```